# What’s the difference between I couldn’t get up at six today and I didn’t get up at six today

Tags: word-usage

I’d like to know what’s the difference between:

> I couldn’t get up at 6:00
>   I didn’t get up at 6:00

Answer (score 1):

*I couldn't* means that you didn't even have a choice to wake up at 6 am while *I didn't* means that you had a **choice** to wake up at 6 am but you chose not to.

Comment: *"I couldn't means that you didn't even have a choice to wake up at 6 am"* - this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> **I couldn’t get up at 6:00**

This means something was stopping you from getting up e.g. you were too tired to get up

> **I didn’t get up at 6:00**

Means there is no real reason why you did not get up, you just didn't get up.